# Rails3 layout not render for some controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

This is my application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 layout :my_layout
 private
 def my_layout
   request.path.match(/folder/) ? 'layout1' : 'layout2'
 end
end
```

In this controller default layout method called and layout2 render post/promotion_controller.rb

```
class Post::PromotionsController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

But in this controller user/users_request_controller.rb layout method not called and no layout render

```
class User::UserRequestsController < User::UserController
 def index
 end
end

class User::UserController < ApplicationController
      def index
      end
end
```

Please help me why my layout method not called.
I am using rails3.2.14 and ruby 1.9.3p392

Comment: Are you inheriting from `ApplicationController` in your `User::UserController` ?

Comment: Yes I am inherit User::UserController to ApplicationController

Comment: Why does User::UserRequestsController subclass User::UserController rather than ApplicationController?

Comment: Here I have use some method of User::UserController instead of create a new one

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring the my_layout method as protected rather than private

That might do the trick